# How Can I Regenerate SSH Keys?

Tags: ssh, openssh, vagrant, sshd, ssh-keys

Here are the keys generated by `ssh` and those are NOT created by me.

```
# ls -l /etc/ssh/
total 276
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     242153 Mar 22  2016 moduli
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       2208 Mar 22  2016 ssh_config
-rw-r--r--  1 root root       4360 Feb 29  2016 sshd_config
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys    227 Mar  5  2015 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        162 Mar  5  2015 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-r-----  1 root ssh_keys    387 Apr  8  2015 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--  1 root root         82 Apr  8  2015 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-r-----. 1 root ssh_keys   1679 Mar  5  2015 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root        382 Mar  5  2015 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

The server having those keys is a Vagrant instance. I have several instances, but unfortunately each instance has the same keys. So, I need to regenerate all the keys to distinguish each server.

How can I regenerate those keys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the old keys, then run:

```
ssh-keygen -A
restorecon /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
```

Note: `moduli` and (obviously) `sshd_config` are not keys and should not be removed.

The hostkeys can also be generated one-by-one using:

```
for type in rsa dsa ecdsa ed25519; do
    ssh-keygen -t ${type} -N "" -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_${type}_key
done
restorecon /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
```

Comment: Could you explain the commands? What does the `-A` flag do, what is `restorecon`? (I do not have the latter command at all, not sure what it should do)

Comment: @Luc: `-A` is the option to auto-generate all "missing" SSH host keys (i.e. it does the thing that OP was asking for). It achieves the same as the individual ssh-keygen commands at the bottom of the post. The `restorecon` command is part of SELinux (which OP's system has) and automatically sets the correct SELinux "security context" of those files.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*
$ sudo ssh-keygen -A
```

The `-A` flag automatically generates missing hostkeys:

> Generate host keys of all default key types (rsa, ecdsa, and ed25519) if they do not already exist.  The host keys are generated with the default key file path, an empty passphrase, default bits for the key type, and default comment.  If -f has also been specified, its argument is used as a prefix to the default path for the resulting host key files.  This is used by system administration scripts to generate new host keys.

For OS images, I would recommend not including any hostkeys (run the first command) and scheduling the second command to be run on (first) startup. This should ensure that each cloned/spawned system gets a fresh set of keys and there are no unintended trust relations between them.